# DataBinding to Property equivalent to DataTable's ColumnChanging & ColumnChange events

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding, datatable

I am used to work with DataSets & DataTables and have a lot of events when the DataColumn value is changed.

With `DataTable.ColumnChanging`, I always validated the user input. For example, when changing CustomerID on a Order, I validated that the CustomerID exists on the database.

With `DataTable.ColumnChanged` event, I always bring additional information from the DataBase. For example, after validating that CustomerID provided is a correct value, I get the customer address from the database. (it is JUST an example)

Now that I am trying to work with WPF and DataBinding... how can I do what I did in the past?

I just don't understand how I am supposed to validate a user input: if value is valid then to call a server method; or it not valid, throw an error message and ignore proposed value.

I am already using `PropertyChanged` event for databinding, is it also possible to use to call another server method when the value is changed?

Is there another way to do this without adding events for each property on each class in my `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: You might need an IDataErrorInfo interface

Comment: thanks, let search about it